# Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined react-redux-jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I have error with second test. What is wrong with them? I doing all by docs, but have error: "Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined". I tried with using Provider, but it doesn't help me, maybe i do something wrong?

Can i somehow debug it?

BoardContainer.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import ConnectedBoard,{Board} from './BoardContainer'

import { shallow, configure,mount} from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';



configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

const boards = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'first_board'
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'second_board',
}];

describe('>>>H O M E --- REACT-REDUX (Shallow + passing the {store} directly)',()=> {
  const initialState = {boards: boards};
  const mockStore = configureStore();
  let store, wrapper;

  beforeEach(()=>{
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    wrapper = shallow( <Provider store={store}><ConnectedBoard /></Provider> );

  })


  it('+++ render the connected(SMART) component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('+++ check Prop matches with initialState', () => {
    expect(wrapper.prop('boards')).toEqual(initialState.boards);
  });

})
```

BoardContainer.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {loadBoards} from '../../actions/boardJS'
import Board from '../../components/Board/Board'

export class BoardContainer extends Component {
  getBoards() {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL + `todo_lists`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.props.dispatch(loadBoards(data))
        })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBoards()
  }

  render() {
    return <Board/>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    boards: state.boards
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BoardContainer)
```

If someone know solution it would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at the props of the Provider Component not the ConnectedBoard component.

I'd also be mindful of the below:

"When called on a shallow wrapper, .prop(key) will return values for props on the root node that the component renders, not the component itself." - https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html

Can you elaborate a bit, you say that property 'prop' is missing, but that would mean that wrapper does not have a ShallowWrapper assigned. Which would mean beforeEach has not executed... I doubt that's the case if test 1 was successful.

Was the error infact that props itself is not defined? When you try to access the property 'boards'